# Switch from Kodi to Raspberry OS

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I have a Raspberry 4 B running KODI on libreelec (base minimum OS wit just enough functionality to run KODI). As I don't use KODI anymore, I want to switch it to Raspberry OS (to later install Foundry VTT Server). Do I have to flash the SD Card anew with Raspberry OS or can I do it with ssh / directly (There is a Bluetooth keyboard /w touchpad connected and i have access via ssh)?

Comment: You don't mention what operating system (OS) you currently run. If you're running KODI using something like libreelec, then you would need to flash a new OS as the OS that comes with libreelec is "just enough to run KODI" (their words) - if you run KODI using something like OSMC, then, perhaps there is a way to just remove KODI

Comment: It is running libreelec, so the "just enough to run KODI" option. If you are certain that there is now way to put Raspberry OS on the card without removing and flashing it with a cardreader (which I absolutely agree is the easiest solution), please provide this as an answer I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Flashing the SD is likely the easiest.
If it were me, I would purchase a new SD card and flash the new OS onto that. Also, you might consider Ubuntu over Raspian, depending on your use case. They are both built on Debian, but I much prefer Ubuntu over Raspian, if for nothing else than the aesthetics.